# Write a JavaScript Function to Create a JSON Body

Tags: javascript, json, rest, http-post, postman

I want to create a JSON Body just like below but using a JavaScript function.

```
{
  "events": [{
    "eventNameCode": {
      "codeValue": "xyz api call"
    },
    "originator": {
      "associateID": "XYZ",
      "formattedName": "ZYX ABC"
    },
    "actor": {
      "associateID": "Akshat",
      "formatedName": "Akshat Shah"
    },
    "data": {
      "eventContext": {
        "contextExpressionID": "Bslfnjsnkcls=",
        "GroupCode": {
          "codeValue": "ccode"
        },
        "RCode": {
          "codeValue": "CALI"
        },
        "dConfiguration": {
          "itemID": "XYZ"

        }
      },
      "transform": {
        "dConfiguration": {
          "Details": [{

            "_modificationCode": "add",
            "ID": {

              "idValue": "IDCode"
            },
            "ReportIndicator": false,
            "Indicator": true,
            "NumDetails": {
              "NumCode": {
                "codeValue": "CodeValue"
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Is there any way I can do that without using any NPM Packages.

The way Java have JSON Builder how do I create some kind of function which can give me this kind of JSON Object.

Comment: Try https://app.quicktype.io/.  Note that your JSON does not validate.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which creates a JavaScript object literal and uses `JSON.stringify()` to convert the object into JSON.

```
function foo() {
  var item = {
    events: [
      {
        eventNameCode: {
          "codeValue": "xyz api call"
        },
        ... // your additional properties removed for brevity
      }
    ]};
  return JSON.stringify(item);
}
```

`JSON.stringify()` is available in all modern browsers *and* modern versions of Node.

Comment: I am still using the entire object. I want to remove the entire object and from the code and create this request JSON Body just using the function it self.